# Background images on buttons are not working

Tags: css

I have 6 buttons, corresponding to Github, StackOverflow, SoloLearn, Facebook, Instagram and Google+, respectevely.
They all have the same style except for the background image.
Only the GitHub, StackOverflow and SoloLearn images are working as backgrounds for the buttons, the other 3 aren't.
Here is the style of the buttons:

```
.github{
    background-image: url('github.png');
    background-color: #000016;
}
.stackoverflow{
    background-image: url('stackoverflow.png');
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.sololearn{
    background-image: url('sololearn.png');
    background-color: #fffeee;
}
.facebook{
    background-image: url('facebook.png');
    background: #3b5998;
}
.instagram{
    background-image: url('instagram.png');
    background: #e1306c;
}
.google{
    background-image: url('google.png');
    background: #dd4b39;
}
.github, .stackoverflow, .sololearn, .facebook, .instagram, .google{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
.github:hover, .stackoverflow:hover, .sololearn:hover, .facebook:hover, .instagram:hover, .google:hover{
    opacity: 0.7;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

In the snippet the images are from a link of my Pinterest images, but in the original code the images are all PNG and are in the same folder as the 'index.html' but only the first 3 work.
Note: I don't want to use any library to add social media icons.
Here is all the code:

```css
body{
 background-color: black;
}
.icons{
 position: fixed;
 top: 50%;
 right: 0;
 transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

/* The problem is in this 6 classes, 3 work, 3 don't */
.github{
 background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/236x/17/54/08/1754081a6e8a0fb06bca25a6c4fb8e53.jpg');
 background-color: #000016;
}
.stackoverflow{
 background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/236x/45/08/1f/45081f65af75c20862452b64d03ebbef.jpg');
 background-color: #ffffff;
}
.sololearn{
 background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/236x/e9/5e/d6/e95ed6e5221c358cddd3aa43cfcc01d1.jpg');
 background-color: #fffeee;
}
.facebook{
 background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/236x/3c/86/dd/3c86dd4de8cfd2201fcc365c3ed4a9b2.jpg');
    background: #3b5998;
}
.instagram{
 background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/236x/4e/28/a9/4e28a95b1f16ccc371707deb4c2e408f.jpg');
    background: #e1306c;
}
.google{
 background-image: url('https://i.pinimg.com/236x/fb/29/40/fb2940721465135b01583ff6f3b668ac.jpg');
    background: #dd4b39;
}
.github, .stackoverflow, .sololearn, .facebook, .instagram, .google{
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: none;
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
    color: white;
    margin-top: -2px;
}
.github:hover, .stackoverflow:hover, .sololearn:hover, .facebook:hover, .instagram:hover, .google:hover{
 opacity: 0.7;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>btns</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="icons">
 <!-- All the 6 buttons are equal except for the class but their classes are also the same except the bg image -->
 <form action="https://github.com/AfonsoHipolito" target="_blank">
  <button type='submit' title='GitHub' class="github"></button>
 </form>
 <form action="https://stackoverflow.com/users/11216714/afonso-hip%c3%b3lito" target="_blank">
  <button type="submit" title="StackOverflow" class="stackoverflow"></button>
 </form>
 <form action="https://www.sololearn.com/Profile/9031845" target="_blank">
  <button type='submit' title='Sololearn' class="sololearn"></button>
 </form>
 <form action="https://www.facebook.com/afonso.hipolito.984" target="_blank">
  <button type='submit' title='Facebook' class="facebook"></button>
 </form>
 <form action="https://www.instagram.com/_afonsohipolito_/" target="_blank">
  <button type='submit' title='Instagram' class="instagram"></button>
 </form>
 <form action="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
  <button type='submit' title='Google' class="google"></button>
 </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why complicating with a form, inputs and background image? use simple image with links

Comment: This is only part of the code, each button opens the link in another page and to a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `background: #...` instead of `background-color: #...`

Which means you overwritten the background you wrote on the previous line. So either move this line to the top or change it with suffix `-color`.

Comment: Thanks! How didn't I see that?!